# Extract Rar File on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, rar

`unrar` used to be available on EPEL repository.  But now, it is gone.

I noticed that  CERT Forensics Tools [has it](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/forensics-x86_64/unrar-5.4.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) now, then I installed it, `unrar e [my file]` works but using Archive Manager (GUI) doesn't work with rar files.

I also tried `unar` as [this article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-extract-rar-files-in-centos-rhel-7-and-8/) suggested.  Same issue.

Any clue how to get it work with Archive Manager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download `rar` from [here](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).

Then do:

```
tar xzvf /pathtofile/rarlinux-your_version.tar.gz
ln -s /pathtofile/rar/rar /usr/bin/rar
ln -s /pathtofile/rar/unrar /usr/bin/unrar
```

The command to decompress with `unrar` is:

```
unrar x filename.part1.rar
```

or `rar`

```
rar x filename.part1.rar
```

Make sure all the files are in the current directory.

Sample output:

```
Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r36

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r37

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r38

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r39

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r40

...         myfile1                                                   OK 
All OK
```

Or use rpmfusion:

`rpmfusion` can be found [here](http://rpmfusion.org/).

rpmfusion [configuration Centos](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)

RHEL 7 or compatible like CentOS:

```
sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: didn't notice that rpmfusion nonfree repos has `unrar` for centos 7.  thanks for pointing to it!

Comment: @HCSF No sweat! My pleasure.