# How to install rar in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, rar

I am trying to install rar in Kali Linux to create a rar archive file. I have followed articles that says to use this command:
`sudo apt install rar`. However, it returns with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package rar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'rar' has no installation candidate
```

I also try to search rar with `aptitude search rar | grep rar`, but I can't find rar.
I have also updated Kali Linux with `sudo apt update`

EDIT:
`rar` can now be installed on Kali Linux. See https://packages.debian.org/sid/rar.

Comment: here is your answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690575/extract-rar-file-on-centos-7/690597#690597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the last version of `rar` from official site and install it. The [link to download](https://www.win-rar.com/fileadmin/winrar-versions/rarlinux-x64-612.tar.gz).

Comment: `rar` has been added to Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The package `rar` has been removed from Kali Linux. [See here](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/rar).

You can install [`unrar-nonfree`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/unrar-nonfree) providing the `unrar` command.

Comment: `unrar` only extracts files from a rar file. It will not make a rar file.